# The method getApplication() is undefined for the type (my class)

Tags: java, android, variables, undefined, global

I am using a global variables "GlobalVariables" in a separated class and I am try to use it in the following code but it is always gives me the error :

```
The method getApplication() is undefined for the type UploadPicture
```

I tried the following but still have error:

```
((GlobalVariables) this.getApplication()).set_FileUploading(false);
```

The qustion was already asked here but unfortunatlly all the answors didn't work with me and gave me same error! any suggestion please?

```
public class UploadPicture extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
private String mPath;
private File mFile;
private long mFileLen;
private UploadRequest mRequest;
private Context mContext;
private String mErrorMsg;
private File outFiles;

public UploadPicture(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath, File file) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    mFileLen = file.length();
    mApi = api;
    mPath = dropboxPath;
    mFile = file;        
}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
        String path = mPath + outFiles.getName();
        mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                new ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public long progressInterval() {
                return 500;
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                //publishProgress(bytes);
            }
        }
        );

        if (mRequest != null) {
            mRequest.upload();
            ((GlobalVariables) UploadPicture.this.getApplication()).set_FileUploading(false);               
            return true;
        }

    } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
        // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
        mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
    } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
        // File size too big to upload via the API
        mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
    } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
        // We canceled the operation
        mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
    } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
        // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
        // but we don't do anything special with them here.
        if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
            // automatically log the user out in this case.
        } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
            // Not allowed to access this
        } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
            // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
            // thumbnailed)
        } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
            // user is over quota
        } else {
            // Something else
        }
        // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
        mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
        if (mErrorMsg == null) {
            mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
        }
    } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
        // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
        mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
    } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
        // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
        mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        // Unknown error
        mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Edit: I am adding now my "VariableGlobales" calss:

```
public  class  GlobalVariables extends Application {
private Boolean _IsIOIORunning=false;
private Boolean _FileUploading=false;

public Boolean get_IsIOIORunning()
{
    return _IsIOIORunning;
}    
public void set_IsIOIORunning(Boolean _IsIOIORunning)
{
    this._IsIOIORunning = _IsIOIORunning;
}


public Boolean get_FileUploading()
{
    return _FileUploading;
}    
public void set_FileUploading(Boolean _FileUploading)
{
    this._FileUploading = _FileUploading;
}
```

Comment: what is getApplication method do? Why do you keep that reference in your GlobalVariables class?

Comment: What is GlobalVariables ? Does it extend Application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal UploadPicture doesn't extend GlobalVariables but it extend AsyncTask.

That it's my "GlobalVariables "

```
public class AppInfo extends Application {

    private static Context context;
    private static String user;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        AppInfo.context = getApplicationContext();
        user = null;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext()           {return AppInfo.context;}
    public static String getUser()                  {return user;}

    public static void setUser(String user)         {AppInfo.user = user;}
}
```

And I call it everywhere like that:

```
AppInfo.getUser();
```

Edit:

GlobalVariables should use static method and variables:

```
public  class  GlobalVariables extends Application {
private static Boolean _IsIOIORunning=false;
private static  Boolean _FileUploading=false;

public static Boolean get_IsIOIORunning() {
    return _IsIOIORunning;
}

public static void set_IsIOIORunning(Boolean _IsIOIORunning) {
    GlobalVariables._IsIOIORunning = _IsIOIORunning;
}

public static Boolean get_FileUploading(){
    return _FileUploading;
}

public static void set_FileUploading(Boolean _FileUploading){
    GlobalVariables._FileUploading = _FileUploading;
}
}
```

Comment: I actually already imported the GlobaleVariables calss "import my.Application.Name.GlobalVariables;" but still not working.So do you mean we can't use a global variable here??

Comment: So that should work: GlobalVariables.this.getApplication().set_FileUploading(false);. I'm, using a global class in my android app so it should work with you too

Comment: I got: "No enclosing instance of the type GlobalVariables is accessible in scope" and also "The method getApplication() is undefined for the type GlobalVariables"

Comment: Is it a static method?

Comment: No, I just added my "GloableVariables" class to my question. so do you mean I have to make it as a static as in your class?

Comment: It's for that, put everything on static, look at my answer I will edit it.